# Textbox width is changing depending on number of HtmlAttributes

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following cshtml file:

```
@using UniHockey.Models
@model UniHockey.Models.Game
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Game";
}
<div id="Team1PlayerScores">
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Team1.Players.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Team1.Players[i].Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Team1.Players[i].GoalsForCurrentGame, new { htmlAttributes = new { min = 0, max = 99, onchange = "updateTeamScore('Team1PlayerScores', 'Team1Score')" } })
    }

</div>
```

I noticed the width of the textbox changes depending on the combination of HTML attributes that I apply in the `Html.EditorFor()` method.

Here are the two different sizes I get:

[image: small]

[image: big]

Here is the truth table I used to test all combinations of the 3 attributes (where 1 means that attribute was applied):

```
min max onchange
001 - big
010 - big
011 - big
100 - big
101 - big
110 - small
111 - small
```

As you can see the textbox is always big unless BOTH the min and max HTML attributes are present, if at least one is missing, the textbox width is large.

Here is the HTML produced by the `Html.EditFor()` helper method:

Big textbox:

```
Travis<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field GoalsForCurrentGame must be a number." data-val-required="The GoalsForCurrentGame field is required." id="Team1_Players_0__GoalsForCurrentGame" min="0" name="Team1.Players[0].GoalsForCurrentGame" onchange="updateTeamScore(&#39;Team1PlayerScores&#39;, &#39;Team1Score&#39;)" type="number" value="0" />
</div>
```

Small textbox:

```
Travis<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field GoalsForCurrentGame must be a number." data-val-required="The GoalsForCurrentGame field is required." id="Team1_Players_0__GoalsForCurrentGame" max="99" min="0" name="Team1.Players[0].GoalsForCurrentGame" type="number" value="0" />
</div>
```

Why is this happening?

**EDIT:**

This is the CSS for when the textbox is large:

```
element.style {
}
user agent stylesheet
input:not([type]), input[type="email" i], input[type="number" i], input[type="password" i], input[type="tel" i], input[type="url" i], input[type="text" i] {
    padding: 1px 0px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    cursor: text;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button, meter, progress {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}
```

and for when it's small:

```
element.style {
}
user agent stylesheet
input:not([type]), input[type="email" i], input[type="number" i], input[type="password" i], input[type="tel" i], input[type="url" i], input[type="text" i] {
    padding: 1px 0px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    cursor: text;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button, meter, progress {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}
```

They are the same CSS.

Comment: Is that the length change occurs server-side or client-side? If the length changed in client-side due to presence of `min` or `max` attribute, you can check them using `$('single-line').attr('min')` & `$('single-line').attr('max')`, then set corresponding CSS selector which controls textbox length/size.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean sorry. I'm only able to see it change when I see the textbox which is when the UI is loaded.

Comment: Then you may try handle `load` or `ready` (when the DOM is fully loaded) to check if both attributes are exist, while one of them is not exist then set larger value for `size` attribute, otherwise set with smaller value.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect element and looked at the CSS? Have you tried with @Html.TextBoxFor ?